# Function taking a string as table and column name

Tags: postgresql, functions, dynamic-sql, plpgsql, parameter

I'm trying to write a function that will create a new column in a `participation` table based on the presence of a id in `survey_name` table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION survey_participated(_sn text)
  returns void AS
$func$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format($$ALTER TABLE participation ADD COLUMN %I integer DEFAULT 0$$,_sn);
  EXECUTE format($$UPDATE TABLE participation SET %I = 1 WHERE participation.participant_id = %I.participant_id$$,_sn,_sn);
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I keep getting the error:

```
[2017-10-19 12:38:09] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "TABLE"
[2017-10-19 12:38:09] Where: PL/pgSQL function survey_participated(text) line 4 at EXECUTE
```

Can someone point out my mistake?

Comment: `update participation set ...` (no `table` keyword)

Comment: Having read @ErwinBrandstetter comment I think he's right and I read your query wrong entirely. I think you want a join or EXISTS in that `UPDATE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is the syntax for `UPDATE` doesn't permit an optional `TABLE` after. It's just not needed. `UPDATE` only operates on tables; `ALTER` works on many targets. The second problem is that should be `%s` (literal/string) and not `%I` (identifier).

```
EXECUTE format(
  $$ALTER TABLE participation ADD COLUMN %I integer DEFAULT 0;$$,
  _sn
);
EXECUTE format(
  $$
    UPDATE participation
    SET %I = 1
    WHERE participation.participant_id = quote_literal(%s||participant_id);
  $$,
  _sn,
  _sn
);
```

That all said, this seems like a horrible idea. You're adding a column to the table, and setting the value of that column to the "colname+id"? How is that useful?

Comment: The problematic part is the keyword `table` after `update`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name missed that, fixed now. ;)

Comment: @AlokShenoy because `%I` will wrap the binding value inside `"` which is not what you want, you just want it to single-quote escape the value so you can concatenate it with `participant_id` safely. Assuming _sn = 5, with `%I` you would get `"5"||participant_id` referring to the column in the query by the name/alias of `"5"`

Comment: The predicate `WHERE participation.participant_id = quote_literal(%s||participant_id);` never evaluates to `true`. Certainly not what the OP wanted, even if he accepted.

Comment: I did accept it because it did point me in the right direction. I think the confusion arose due to the way I had framed the question. @EvanCarrollQWERHJKL, thank you.